# How to use multiple tables in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables, one is products and another one is buyers. Product table has id, product name and manufacturer fields and buyers table has id, buyer name and quantity. I want only product name, buyer name and quantity based on the id. How to write code for this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give details on the relationship between the two tables, so I'll assume a new row is created in 'buyer' for each purchase.

In that case, CakePHP can take care of most of it for you, if you set the models up correctly.

1. Add a 'products_id' column to the buyer table
2. In the model definition for buyer, add the following:
   `var $belongsTo = 'Product';`

Now when you run a `$this->Buyer->find('all')`, you'll get the buyer and product data returned in the array.

More information on model associations can be found here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together